# DataTables RowsGroup plugin can't work when use JSON.stringify(responeText[1]) BUT manually declare data work fine

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

Manual Declare data (Work fine):

```
var data = [
                            ["imran_15","David","Maths","80","20","10"],
                            ["imran_15","David","Maths","80","20","10"],
                            ["farhana_06","SIP/8002","03-09-2016","06:57:17am","03-09-2016","04:01:41pm"],
                            ["imran_15","SIP/8001","03-09-2016","03:59:35pm","03-09-2016","09:55:14pm"],
                            ["jannatul_66","SIP/8003","03-09-2016","10:15:34am","03-09-2016","10:26:26am"],
                            ["jannatul_66","SIP/8003","03-09-2016","10:26:31am","03-09-2016","03:59:33pm"],
                        ];
```

var data = JSON.stringify(responeText[1]); Output here:

```
[
["imran_15","David","Maths","80","20","10"],
["imran_15","David","Maths","80","20","10"],
["imran_15","David","Maths","80","20","10"],
["farhana_06","SIP/8002","03-09-2016","06:57:17am","03-09-2016","04:01:41pm"],
["imran_15","SIP/8001","03-09-2016","03:59:35pm","03-09-2016","09:55:14pm"],
["jannatul_66","SIP/8003","03-09-2016","10:15:34am","03-09-2016","10:26:26am"],
["jannatul_66","SIP/8003","03-09-2016","10:26:31am","03-09-2016","03:59:33pm"]
```

]
My JS:

```
var data = JSON.stringify(responeText[1]);
            $('#table_id').DataTable({
                "lengthMenu": [ [10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"] ],
                "columns": [
                        {
                            name: 'first',
                            title: 'Agent Name',
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'second',
                            title: 'Extension',
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'third',
                            title: 'Login Date',
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'fourth',
                            title: 'Login Time',
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'fifth',
                            title: 'Logout Date',
                        },
                        {
                            name: 'sixth',
                            title: 'Logout Time',
                        },
                    ],
                "data": data,


                "rowsGroup": [
                              'first:name',
                            ],  
            });
```

When show me some error:
First Alert: DataTables warning: table id=table_id - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
Second Alert: DataTables warning: table id=table_id - Requested unknown parameter '1' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Please anyone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` property of DataTables expects an array, not a string, so you don't need to stringify the data at all:

```
var data = responeText[1];
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. it's working. one more thing, how to show middle of the cell in rowspan data.